# »Sie liebte ihn so sehr, dass sie es vorzog, ihn weiter zu lieben, statt ihn zu täuschen, auch wenn sie ihm das auf brutale Weise mitteilen musste«

Tags: subjunctive, conjunction

> Sie liebte ihn so sehr, dass sie es vorzog, ihn weiter zu lieben, statt ihn zu täuschen, **auch wenn sie ihm das auf brutale Weise mitteilen musste**.

Könntet Ihr mir bitte sagen, ob das fett markierte Ereignis als tatsächlich geschehen betrachtet werden kann? Heißt das, dass es sich um eine reale Handlung handelt und sie ihm dies tatsächlich „auf brutale Weise“ mitteilte? 
Liege ich falsch, wenn ich sage, dass die Aktion hypothetisch wäre, wenn der Satz so formuliert wäre:

> … ***selbst wenn*** sie ihm das auf brutale Weise mitteilen **müsste**?

Answer (score 1):

Ja, das ist tatsächlich geschehen.

Die hypothetische Aktion wäre allerdings mit

> ...selbst wenn sie ihm das auf brutalste Weise hätte mitteilen müssen

ausgedrückt worden. Deine Konstruktion passt nur zu einem Geschehen in der Gegenwart ("sie liebt ihn so sehr, dass sie es vorzieht...")

Answer (score 0):

Das kommt darauf an, wo der Originaltext herstammt. In erzählerischen Texten, die durchgehend in der Vergangenheitsform gehalten sind, ist es *nicht klar*. Denn dann wäre der entsprechende Satz im Präsens etwa:

> […] auch wenn sie ihm das auf brutalste Weise mitteilen muss.

Präsens und Futur sind im Deutschen nicht klar voneinander getrennt, demnach ist nicht klar, ob sie ihm das bereits mitteilt oder ob es erst in Kürze passieren wird. Dass es passieren wird, ist allerdings wahrscheinlich, sofern nicht noch weitere Wenden auftreten.

Wenn allerdings der Großteil des Textes im Präsens formuliert ist, muss man davon ausgehen, dass sie es ihm auf jeden Fall mitgeteilt hat.

---

Bezüglich der Konjuntivanalyse hat Tofro Recht, im Präsens muss die Verbform *müsste* sein, in der Vergangenheit *hätte … müssen*.